# How to preserve the values from client-side after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, textbox, postback

I have a asp:TextBox where I input a value with the keyboard and then I click an asp:Button to save this value in database.

Everything is working fine the way as I said, with the keyboard, but if I tried to assign the value by jQuery with a div resizable... the value set with jQuery is not passing to server side. In fact, when I debug I see the value is the old one that I entered by keyboard before. Thus, How can I do to preserve the javascript assigned value during the postback?

This is the function that changes my unrecognized values with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#divResizable").resizable({
            resize: function (event, ui) {
                var width = ui.size.width;
                $("[id$=txtWidth]").val(width);
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to preserve the values from client-side after postback?

Session State, Cookies, Local Storage, Server Memory or Database.

> For your particular use case.

I'd store the data in a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/HTTP_cookies).